# this.fn is not a function when submitting a checkout.js form

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, checkout

I'm getting an error when trying to submit a Stripe checkout form.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://sugarcereal.com/bid" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="7GVWWPe71ETA9ApL7MZF03Hx3g0tAWRaJ4iWl0dS">

<div>
    <label for="url">URL</label>
   <input placeholder="url" name="url" type="text">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="bid_amount">Bid Amount</label>
    <input placeholder="bid_amount" name="bid_amount" type="text" value="200" id="bid_amount">
</div>

<div>
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

<script>
    var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_my_key',
    image: 'logo.png',
    locale: 'auto'
  });

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
// Open Checkout with further options
handler.open({
  name: 'Co. Name',
  description: 'Bid',
  amount: $('#bid_amount').val()
});
e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
handler.close();
});
</script>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is that the entire callstack? Its not originating in your code if it is. It may be that either you have to update stripe because the one you have has a bug or there is an event handler you're supposed to be subscribing to. I'm not really sure.

Comment: You don't have a token callback supplied, you need to supply one so that you can receive the response from Checkout

Answer (score 1):

Matthew answered above as a comment. I was missing a token callback function.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a token callback function.  I am having the same problem.

Comment: The Stripe Checkout custom integration workflow requires that a `token` value be defined as part of the object passed into `StripeCheckout.configure()`. The token value should be a function that will be executed after successfully receiving a response from Stripe, and is responsible for submitting the received token to your own backend server.